How to prove this relation for Kendall's distribution function (or Kendall's measure)
Kendall Distribution Function (Nelsen, 2006, p. 163) Or Kendall Measure (Salvadori et al., 2007, p. 148) Or Kendall Function (Joe, 2014, pp. 419–422) is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the $U=(u,v)$ where $U$ is distributed as the copula: $U\sim C(u,v)$. Letting $Z$ be the random variable for $C(u,v) : Z=C(u,v)$, the Kendall Function is defined as
$$F_K(z;C)=Pr(Z\leq z;U\sim C(u,v))$$
Joe (2014) does not explicitly list an expression of $F_K(z)$ that is computable directly for any $C(u,v)$, and Nelsen (2006, p. 163) only lists a form for Archimedean copulas. Salvadori et al. (2007, eq. 3.47, p. 147) also list the Archimedean form; however, Salvadori et al. (2007, eq. 3.49, p. 148) also list a form computable directly for any $C(u,v)$ as:
$$F_K(z)=z+\int_{z}^{1} \frac{\partial C(u,t)}{\partial u} du$$
where $t=C^{(-1)}(u,z)$ for $0 \leq z \leq 1$.
My Question: how Salvadori derived this form for Kendall function?

Try to start by this: _(;)=(≤;∼(,)), rewrite it as: _(;)=(C(u,v) ≤;∼(,)). Then, use the non-decreasing property of copula to have FK(z; C) = Pr(C(u,z) ≤ z; U ~ C(u,v)). I think it would help.
